# HATEOAS and Angular Routes

Tags: angular, rest, single-page-application, hateoas

I have an Angular 4 (soon to be 5!) application.

It talks to a REST API which uses the HATEOAS technique so that when I make a service call I have links to operations available as the result of that request.. For instance if I request a person object the API would give me links so that I could call update and delete on that person, or I could call create a new person.

What I am interested in is the ability to map HATEOAS operations to routes in angular. E.g. HATEOAS is telling me that I can create a new customer.. But I would like to map that to the component in Angular that allows me to create a new customer... E.g. so I know what component services the request I am allowed to make.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/mdvorak/resource-router _Angular routing engine that drive views by media types. It loads data itself, and by response Content-Type header it displays configured view. It is a replacement for original Angular Router (they cannot be used at the same time)._